# Does the Cisco SF 302-08P Small Business Switch support accounting commands to tacacs?

Tags: cisco, tacacs, accounting

We have a handful of small business switches from cisco, model SF 302-08P.  I'm trying to configure them for full tacacs support, however it appears that the model only supports tacacs for authentication, not for accounting.

Below is the version info and relevant configuration that I have so far.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
SW version    1.1.2.0 ( date  12-Nov-2011 time  23:34:26 )
Boot version    1.1.0.6 ( date  11-May-2011 time  18:31:00 )
HW version    V02
```

```
aaa authentication enable default tacacs enable
aaa authentication login default tacacs local
tacacs-server host 10.3.1.1 key redacted    priority 3
tacacs-server host 10.2.1.1 key redacted    priority 2
tacacs-server host 10.1.1.1 key redacted
```

Comment: AFAICT SG300 series switches only support tacacs authentication. [Ref](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps10898/data_sheet_c78-610061.html).  Unrelated, but useful if you dont know; hopefully you got the [1.1 FW](http://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-17092), which includes CDP support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering, so [community](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) will quit bumping this active...

> We have a handful of small business switches from cisco, model SF 302-08P. I'm trying to configure them for full tacacs support, however it appears that the model only supports tacacs for authentication, not for accounting.

As of [firmware version 1.3.7.18](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/sg300-10mp-10-port-gigabit-max-poe-managed-switch/model.html), you can configure tacacs accounting for login / logout; however, there is no support for per-command accounting listed in the user manual (ref: [Cisco Sx300 Series Administration Guide, Version 1.3.7](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/csbms/sf30x_sg30x/administration_guide/AG_Cisco_Sx300_1_3_7_en.pdf), chapter 21, pages 402-403).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot:

```
aaa new-model
```

Try and see if that works.

Comment: These devices don't run a full version of IOS; I'm not even sure you could call it IOS.  There's no aaa new-model on these devices.  The authentication/authorization works fine, I just can't log commands via the accounting subsystem like I can through normal IOS.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be of more assistance :(